# WCF REST: specify content-type on WebGet Attribute doesn't seem to be working

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010, rest

probably something i doing wrong, but i am returning XML from my WCF Rest service which is built with VS 2010. In fiddler you can see here that it returns test/html as the content-type

```
 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 Cache-Control: private
 Content-Length: 222
 Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
 Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
 X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
 Date: Mon, 16 Aug 2010 20:49:55 GMT
```

So i went ahead and added the following on the webget attribute on my method but it still returns text/html ... I presume that i should return the content type of text/xml because i am in fact returning XML?

Heres my method, i added the ResponseFormat to the attribute...  I wasn't sure if i needed bodystyle (i have no idea what it does but saw it in an example :-) )

```
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
    public List<SampleItem> GetCollection()
    {
        // TODO: Replace the current implementation to return a collection of SampleItem instances
        return new List<SampleItem>() { new SampleItem() { Id = 1, StringValue = "Hello" } };
    }
```

anyway after the change and rebuilding of the project it still returns the wrong content type ... am i missign somthing?

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 222
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 16 Aug 2010 20:54:15 GMT
```

**EDIT**

Ok i got a working solution but the attribute method has NO EFFECT, very strange...but if i put this

```
  WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/xml";
```

Now i check fiddler and the content-type is actually text/xml.

But i need to put this in every method and the attribute method seems to have no effect.

Anybody know why?

Comment: I get it working, but i don't understand why the attribute has NO EFFECT. I will update my question..

Comment: Not sure if you're still interested in this question (it's been a few days), but how are you requesting this service?  jQuery, something else?  I think you're getting text/html because that is what's being sent up in the request's Accept header (or ContentType).  Can you update with how you're requesting the service and what fiddler is saying your request headers are?  Thanks!

Comment: Hi D Hoerster, yes i am still interested... I am doing a simple request using firefox and my headers are included in question above....  Copied and pasted from fiddler. Thanks

Comment: Don't put it in every method. Simply call it once in the constructor.

Answer (score 6):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4822190/134761) the Firefox request headers has a higher priority for *text/html* than *text/xml*, resulting in WCF service methods decorated with xml or json returning with the "wrong" response, although I can imagine it is the correct behavior.

You can force a response content type by explicitly setting

```
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/xml";
```

or equivalent. I guess this is the only alternative if you truly want to force a specific content type response for all browsers/clients.

Answer (score 0):

See e.g.

[WCF ResponseFormat For WebGet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992533/wcf-responseformat-for-webget/1016266#1016266)

I think you want e.g.

```
OutgoingWebResponseContext context = 
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse; 
context.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
```

`ResponseFormat` controls something else.

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks ... well i have been reading this and unless i am mistaken... this is for when you want to return CUSTOM formats that are not supported but the xml format is supported .....  see here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webgetattribute.aspx

So i assume it should work but its not

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but here is what I found on MSDN's Blog [Getting Started with WCF WebHttp Services in .NET 4](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2010/01/07/getting-started-with-wcf-webhttp-services-in-net-4.aspx):

Your project has to use the Full .NET 4 Framework, not the Client Profile.

Once I did that, and restarted the project, I was able to add **System.ServiceModel.Web** from the list of References.

I hope this helps someone.