# Display the contents of the file to the browser instead of downloading it

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest

I'm trying to build a simple RESTful application. I have a WFC service.

In interface i have next method:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "get")]
Stream GetPage();
```

And implements this method:

```
public System.IO.Stream GetPage()
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ms);
    sw.WriteLine("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
    sw.WriteLine("Content-Type: text/html");
    sw.Write(Properties.Resources.page);
    sw.Flush();
    ms.Position = 0;
    return ms;
}
```

Resource.page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    Hello word!!!
</body>
</html>
```

But when i go to `localhost/MyService/Get` the browser downloads the file instead of displaying it.

How to show this content in browser?

Comment: Are you trying to create a RESTful application / service, or a web server?

Comment: RESTful service. I understand that my service is working properly. Now I need to display the result in the client.

Comment: Is your client a web browser (That talks to a web server, and expects an HTTP response)?

Comment: Why do you want to return HTML from a REST service? Why do you use WCF and not WebAPI?

Comment: @Amit, yes, client is web browser. And i want show content in browser. I used Fiddler to see what response i getting. The server returns `Content-Type: application/octet-stream`.. But why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you create a ["raw" WCF REST response method](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2008/04/17/wcf-raw-programming-model-web.aspx) by letting it return a `Stream`, you still only have control over the response body of the HTTP message using that stream.

So the HTTP headers you write into the stream that you return will be seen as content, not headers by the receiver.

You need to explicitly set the header as explained in [WCF REST: specify content-type on WebGet Attribute doesn't seem to be working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3497263/wcf-rest-specify-content-type-on-webget-attribute-doesnt-seem-to-be-working):

```
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/html";
```