# How can I return bare result back to WCF client

Tags: wcf, wcf-rest

I have code something like the following:

```
<OperationContract()>
<Description("")>
<WebGet(Bodystyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate:="TestConnection")>
Function TestConnection() As String


Public Function TestConnection() As String Implements ITestSvc.TestConnection
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/plain"
    Return "Connection Success"
End Function
```

But it returns is `<string xmlns='...'>Connection Success</string>`

How can I have only "Connection Success" to be returned without XML wrapper.  I know that we can do something with MessageEncoder.  But, I want to have it available at operation level (certain operations need XML/JSON wrappers and certain operations don't).

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is here [WCF ResponseFormat For WebGet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992533/wcf-responseformat-for-webget) (and it worked for me)

Answer (score 12):

here is the simplest solution to return plain text. Set response format to xml and set outgoingresponse to text/html.  Should do the trick.

```
[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
public string DoWork()
{

    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/html";
    return "THIS IS PLAIN TEXT";
}
```

Comment: Does not work for me

Answer (score 3):

There is one way how to achieve this if you're dealing with HTTP, it's not exactly nice, but I thought I could mention it.

You can set the return type of your method to void and just output your raw string directly into the response.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "foo")]
void Foo()
{
   HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("bar");
}
```

Comment: this is good, it helped me while the others not, thanks