# RESTful service returning JSON wrapped in XML Serialization tag?

Tags: .net, json.net

I have a service that attempting to serialize a list into JSON (using JSON.NET) and return as a string.  That's all well and good, but my JSON is coming back wrapped and I can't figure out why.

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">[{"DoNotSolicitID":5,"FirstName":"test","LastName":"mcTest","Address1":"11 Elm St","Address2":null,"City":"testville","State":null,"Zip":null,"Zip4":null,"Email":"test@mcTest.com","Phone":null,"BusinessName":null,"PartnerID":"3","Origination":"RDI"},{"DoNotSolicitID":6,"FirstName":"test","LastName":"mcTest","Address1":"11 Elm St","Address2":null,"City":"testville","State":null,"Zip":null,"Zip4":null,"Email":"test@mcTest.com","Phone":null,"BusinessName":null,"PartnerID":"3","Origination":"RDI"}]</string>
```

The code making the call is:

```
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Lookup(guid, criteria), Formatting.None);

private IList<DNSContract> Lookup(string guid, SearchCriteria criteria)
    {
        apiAuthentication = new APIKeyAuthentication();
        if (!apiAuthentication.IsValidAPIKey(guid))
            throw new WebFaultException<string>("Invalid Key", HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);

        var searchObj = ToSearchObject(criteria);

        SetContext();

        return Svc.SelectWithCriteria(searchObj).Data;
    }
```

**UPDATE:** This is a WCF service and in the browser, and fiddler I get the same XML tags.  Also, making the call from jQuery/ajax blows up, presumably because it's getting the tags as well, not the JSON.

**UPDATE 2:** the SetContext() call will set the ContentType based on the desired type.  In this case I'm simply doing the following for JSON in the base class for the REST services:

```
 OutgoingWebResponseContext response = WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse;
 response.ContentType = "application/json";
 response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
```

So I'm setting the ContentType in teh rsponse and returning a string as a simple output in the service method.  This is the interface I'm implementing:

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/{guid}/search/json?fname={firstname}&lname={lastname}&phone={phone}&email={email}&add1={address1}&add2={address2}&city={city}&state={state}&zip5={zip5}")]
    string LookupRecord(string guid, string firstname, string lastname, string phone, string email, string address1, string address2, string city, string state, string zip5);
```

Perhaps something in the WebGet that I need to explicitly format to be JSON?

Comment: Is your service ASMX? WCF? WCF Web API? If you're using ASMX or WCF then you have no control over the HTTP stream, so the framework is likely munging things there to make the data fit to whatever the return content-type is.

Comment: Ok, so then when returning JSON in a WCF RESTful service, is there a preferred return type?

Comment: yes, `application/json` is the preferred return type for JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem was that I was not setting the context's OutgoingResponse.Format to JSON.  The context code for a valid JSON response in my situation is

```
context.ContentType = "application/json";
context.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
context.Format = WebMessageFormat.Json;
```

Oddly enough, setting the attributes on the web method didn't do anything, I had to set the context explicitly.  Since I need to handle XML and JSON responses, this seems the best approach I've found.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the WebGet/WebInvoke attributes for your handler method you may need to set the ResponseFormat to JSON? [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992533/wcf-responseformat-for-webget)

Comment: Tried it and got the same thing...JSON wrapped in XML.

Comment: Just did a quick test and with [WebGet(UriTemplate = "test/{value}")] I am getting the XML <string/> envelope but with [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "test/{value}")] I get pure JSON, therefor my suggestion but I do not have the same response context you have so that may change things.

Comment: if you were to have your method return a string of "hello world" or whatever, with the JSON ResponseFormat attribute, do you get the raw JSON?  I've tried WebGet and WebInvoke, both setting the ResponseFormat and thus far, it's the same thing. I'll play with it a bit more, thanks.

Comment: @BryanGrimes: Yes, I did get the raw JSON. However, I was trying this on a pretty standard setup while you have some customizations in place - glad you found the solution though in setting the context.Format field!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning a string in your `WebMethod` use:

```
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(YOUR_STRING_TO_OUTPUT));
```