# WCF CustomBehavior set JSON/stream for context

Tags: json, wcf, stream

Similar to this question, I need to send back JSON.
[WCF ResponseFormat For WebGet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992533/wcf-responseformat-for-webget)

But I'm working from within a WCF Behavior being called by a BizTalk 2010 SendPort Adapter.

I'm inside this method:

```
public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
```

So I have the Message and the channel that I can manipulate.

I think the direction is something like this:

1) //WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = “text/plain”;

or

2) OperationContext.Current.... something - but I don't know the object model well.

I'm currently using the MemoryStream:

```
byte[] byteArrayJSON = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strJSON);
MemoryStream memStreamJSON = new MemoryStream(byteArrayJSON); 
//WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = “text/plain”;
Message newMessage = Message.CreateMessage(MessageVersion.None, "", memStreamJSON);
... 
request = newMessage;  // substitute my new message for the original one.
```

My headers have this:

```
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
```

Answer (score 0):

I think these are the lines I need, but still testing...

```
WebBodyFormatMessageProperty bodyFormat = new WebBodyFormatMessageProperty(WebContentFormat.Json);
newMessage.Properties.Add(WebBodyFormatMessageProperty.Name, bodyFormat);
```

It looks like maybe now I should pass XML and this will cause the serialization to happen?  I'm now on to my next error:

```
System.ArgumentException: Encountered unexpected namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.IO'. The namespace must be empty.
Parameter name: ns
```

Going to try "raw":

```
WebBodyFormatMessageProperty bodyFormat = new WebBodyFormatMessageProperty(WebContentFormat.Json);
newMessage.Properties.Add(WebBodyFormatMessageProperty.Name, bodyFormat);
```